# Swap keys within the object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object `x` with numerous objects within:

```
x: {
'2018-02': {
 'chicken': {
  'number': 2
   }
  }
'2018-03': {
 'carrots': {
  'number': 3
   }
  }
'2018-04': {
 'tomatoes': {
  'number': 5
   }
  }
 ...
 }
```

How can I build an object from this object where each food item will be swapped with a date. So I want this structure:

```
x: {
chicken: {
 2018-02: {
  number: 2
   }
  }
carrots: {
 2018-03: {
  number: 3
   }
  }
tomatoes: {
 2018-04: {
  number: 5
   }
  }
 ...
 }
```

UPD: Initially I wanted to have an array from an object but in order to narrow my question I decided to not transform this object and leave it as it is.

Comment: If you want your keys to be anything other than integers, you want an object not an array. That means your original data is fine and you shouldn't try to transform it. Why are you wanting to use arrays instead of objects?

Comment: The loop to compose the structure you want will cost the same than loop the current structure and do whatever you want to do

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It seems like you are asking about an attempted solution to a problem, rather than asking about the problem itself.

Comment: @Paulpro indeed, I don't have to transform this into an array. I wanted to apply `.map()` method on that array later but I realised that I can retrieve data from the object with another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
function swap(obj) {
  var newObj = new Object();
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((entry) => {
    let key = Object.keys(entry[1])[0];
    if (newObj[key] == undefined) newObj[key] = new Object(); //creates newObj[key] if it doesn't exist
    newObj[key][entry[0]] = entry[1][key]; //sets newObj[key][key2]
  });
  return newObj
}
```

When `obj` is your original object.

Comment: It seems to work properly now but can you please explain what is happening in the code when we apply `Object.keys` second time?

Comment: I also noticed that this solution returns only one object (carrots for example). How can I return all transformed objects (chicken, carrots, tomatoes)?

Comment: @OlgaB I fixed it and added explanation comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in javascript to have an array indexed by keys. The structure you want

```
2018-03: [
  number: 3
]
```

is syntactically incorrect. The only way to have named indexes in javascript is to use an object, like what the original structure is.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Why a comment? It answers the question by stating that what they are trying to do is impossible

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP is asking about an attempted solution to their problem, without stating the original problem. It is better to try to get clarification about what they are actually having a problem with, rather than tell them their attempted solution won't work.

Comment: OP asked to take an object and restructure it to a key-indexed array. There's no way to accomplish this with javascript, and so there's no way to answer their question with anything else but 'its impossible'

Comment: "key-indexed array" = object in JavaScript. We have no idea why the OP says they want an "array", or if the OP even understands the difference between an array and an object in JS. IMO it is much more helpful to leave it unanswered until we get clarification.

Comment: the thing is, anyone coming to this question from google or outside of stackoverflow will see this question and assume its possible to create a key-indexed array like what OP suggests. having an answer that clarifies that what OP wants is impossible is valuable to this specific question

Comment: We could also just vote to close as "Unclear what you are asking" and eliminate the confusion. And to be technically correct, it is possible to create a "key-index array". That functionality is exactly what an object is. In fact, there is no such thing as a true array - they are all objects under the hood, just with integer keys and special prototype methods.

Comment: my wording was more so of relation to the question. theres no way in javascript to have an array with the syntax that OP suggests. i do think you have a point with closing the question due to lack of clarity though

Comment: Also technically incorrect. You **can** define string literal properties on arrays and access them, [like so](https://repl.it/@ugam44/SurefootedClearcutPhases). What is in the OP's question is *output*, not syntax for creating array literals. So yes, technically what the OP is asking for is *doable*, but before any of the JS community gives the OP an answer, we must figure out if that is *actually* what they want, or if they are just confused.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't even know that was a thing. Learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: I (personally) have never seen it used in production code. None of the Array prototype methods (forEach, slice, etc) will see those properties, however, they can be accessed just like object properties (because they *are* object properties), and they show up in the `for...in` loop. Which, on a side-note is why people say don't use `for...in` on arrays, because you can get unexpected results like that. `for...of` will give only integer keys - same with JSON.stringify and Array prototype methods. [Here](https://repl.it/@ugam44/SurefootedClearcutPhases) is a good example of some differences